# Two words with different last letter (Arabic)

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing

I made dictionary file for Arabic to be used in LibreOffice and LyX.  It contains over 2.7 million Arabic words.

Sometimes, we can write the word with `ه`, and sometimes with `ة` if it's at the end of the word.

I want to use a script with `sed` or `tr` to say that if there are two words that are the same, except for the last letter, and the last letters of the two words are `ة` and `ه`, delete the word which contains `ه`.

Examples input:

```
الجنة
الجنه
الشجرة
الشجره
```

Output:

```
الجنة 
الشجرة
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but it would make things much clearer if you could give an example with input and the desired output.

Comment: Are there words like a word `الحديقه` that it has no `الحديقة` match? then do you need to convert it to `الحديقة` or you want leave it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v TA=ة -v HA=ه '
        { orig = $0 }
        sub(HA"$", TA) { $0 in ta || ha[$0] = orig; next }
        $0 ~ TA"$" { ta[$0] = 1; delete ha[$0] }
        { print }
        END{ for(i in ha) print ha[i] }
' input_file | LC_ALL=C sort -u > output_file
```

I've tried to do something smarter, by creating a custom `LC_COLLATE`, but didn't manage it ;-)

Comment: Thank you, The code worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :  `cat yourDictionary |grep -i yourWord |sed /$ه/d`

`/$ه/d` - deletes  everything that ends with the special symbol (d flag is for delete)
`grep -i` - match in case-insesitive way 
Also you can also add `-w` to grep to match exactly the string

Comment: I don't think it would be viable to do this for each individual word. I'm also uncertain whether this would work in a left-to-right language (you can't match anything to the right of `$` in the C locale). It also ignores the fact that there may not be a variant of the word that ends with ة.

Comment: My bad ,I misunderstood the question. I though OP asked  for expression that filters only by those chars in a similar words whose difference is only the last symbol.

Comment: The regular expressions always use the logical, not the display order of the characters, so `$` will always match before a newline, whether at the right or at the left.

Comment: As to the 2nd objection, that sounds right -- there may be words with are always written with heh (ه) at the end and never with with teh marbuta (ة).